# Activating Trigger with timestamp

Tags: sql, db2

I need to activate a trigger from a defined time not by Update, Insert etc actions. Do you have any example to help me ?.....Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: As far as I know there is no such thing -- in any database -- of a trigger that runs at a particular time.  You are looking for an event or a job scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's comment is mostly correct...triggers are by definition invoked by the DB during insert/update/delete actions.

If you're trying to re-use logic currently in a trigger, you should consider pulling the logic into some shared procedure that can be used by the trigger and a scheduled task.

However, depending on your Db2 platform & version and the trigger itself, it's possible there's some other option.  For example, with Db2 for IBM i, you can create triggers in SQL or in any native language (RPG,COBOL,C,C++).  With a native trigger, it's not too big a deal to create another program that can invoke the trigger program just like the DB would have.